# App crashes while inserting xml records in to ios device

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, crash, nsmanagedobjectcontext

First here is my crash log

```
Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3b8afc30 __CFBasicHashRehash + 796
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3b8b0e48 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 88
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3b7db194 CFBasicHashAddValue + 3048
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3b7deebc CFSetAddValue + 112
4   CoreData                        0x36ea45b0 -        [NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _insertObjectWithGlobalID:globalID:] + 172
5   CoreData                        0x36e9c9bc -[NSManagedObjectContext insertObject:] +     136
6   CoreData                        0x36e8c6d2 -[NSManagedObject     initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] + 646
7   CoreData                        0x36e78d74 +[NSEntityDescription     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 176
8   XYZ Orders                      0x000f8182 -[ITMLoginVC traverseElement:] (ITMLoginVC.m:1551)
9   XYZ Orders                      0x000f7eba -[ITMLoginVC traverseElement:] (ITMLoginVC.m:1506)
10  XYZ Orders                      0x000f5970 -[ITMLoginVC getAllCustomerValues]     (ITMLoginVC.m:903)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x39b8911c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x39b8d95c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 248
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x39b8dabc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x368f2a0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x368f28a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

The line 903:

```
if(ttbXML.rootXMLElement)
{
    [self traverseElement:ttbXML.rootXMLElement]; //line 903
}
```

The line 1551 :

```
ITMAllCustomerAddresses *allCustAddress =(ITMAllCustomerAddresses *)[NSEntityDescription                                                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ITMAllCustomerAddresses"
                                                                                                                        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

The line 1506 :

```
         [self traverseElement:element->firstChild];
```

I am using TBXML to parse. Here on StackOverflow, people suggested to user TBXML incase of large XML. I used NSXMLParser, but it was slow and crashed. This crashes too, but its fast and crashes like once or twice in a day. This is again a rare case. This is second time i got this today. So i thought i might post this. I thought my managedobjectcontext is not initialised properly so i am doing it right now like this:

```
    if (!self.managedObjectContext)
{
    self.managedObjectContext  = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
}
```

If anyone has any ideas as to why its behaving like this please tell me. If you need more information, let me know. Thanks. Its in iOS6 and i am testing for iPhone device. Its an in-house app. Works fine on Simulator.

Comment: whats in ITMLoginVC.m:1551 ?

Comment: @calvinBhai. Changed the code. Check it out.